# Best way to sync Heroku with git repo?

Tags: git, heroku, github, bitbucket

What is the easiest way to sync **Heroku** (git) with **github** or **bitbucket** (alternative git source) ?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration

Comment: what about bitbucket?

Comment: @bmustata, your question has a [tag:github] tag. Are you actually asking about [tag:bitbucket]? Also, what do you mean by "sync"? What behaviour do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Heroku provides a Github integration. have a look at the docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration

what do you mean with sync? If you want to automatically deploy new commits to your Heroku app, only the GitHub integrations offers you that. I assume that when a new commit is received on GitHub, a hook is sent to Heroku, that will deploy the new code. Bitbucket also has hooks, but probably the integration has not been done because most users are on GitHub

Nevertheless, keep in mind that automatic deploys (to production apps) may be dangerous if the code is not well tested, so it may be preferable to have manual deploys.